# Select from cross-reference based on inclusion (column values being subset)

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a cross-reference table `t` with the following data:

```
| id | a_id | b_id |
--------------------
| 1  | 1    | 1    |
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
| 3  | 1    | 3    |
| 4  | 2    | 7    |
| 5  | 2    | 3    |
| 6  | 3    | 2    |
| 7  | 3    | 3    |
```

What would be the conventional way of selecting all `a_id` whose `b_id` is a subset of a given set?

For example, for some set `(1,2,3,4,5)`, I would expect the result:

```
| a_id |
--------
| 1    |
| 3    |
```

Since `a_id` 1 and 3 are the only set of `b_id` that is a subset of (1,2,3,4,5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . .  One way uses aggregation:

```
select a_id
from t
group by a_id
having sum(case when b_id not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

However, assuming you have an `a` table, then I prefer this method:

```
select a_id
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.a_id = a.a_id and t.b_id not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                 );
```

This saves the expense of aggregation and the lookup can take advantage of an appropriate index (on `t(a_id, b_id)`) so this should have better performance.

Comment: Would it be simpler to just `select distinct a_id from t where b_id in (1,2,3,4,5)`?

Comment: Nope. That would include all a_id having any b_id in the set, not all.