# Select from cross-reference based on inclusion (column values being superset)

Tags: sql

Given a cross-reference table `t` relating table `a` with `b`:

```
| id | a_id | b_id |
--------------------
| 1  | 1    | 1    |
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
| 3  | 1    | 3    |
| 4  | 2    | 7    |
| 5  | 2    | 3    |
| 6  | 3    | 2    |
| 7  | 3    | 3    |
```

What would be the conventional way of selecting all `a_id` whose `b_id` is a superset of a given set?

For example, for the set `(2,3)`, I would expect the result:

```
| a_id |
--------
| 1    |
| 3    |
```

Since `a_id` 1 and 3 are the only set of `b_id` that is a superset of `(2,3)`.

The best solution I've found so far (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36770360/4326531)):

```
select id
from a
where 2 = (select count(*)
           from t
           where t.a_id = a.id and t.b_id in (2,3)
          );
```

But I'd prefer to avoid calculating stuff like cardinality before running the query.

Comment: I assume you mean cardinality of the set `(2, 3)`.  What version of SQL are you using and how are you passing in the values?

Comment: Correct assumption. I'm using postgresql 9. The values are retrieved from a text based external database and stored in table `b` for normalization. So the sample set `(2,3)`  is simply a result from `select b_id from b where value in ('some_string_value', 'another_string_value')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply adapt the query as:

```
select id
from a cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from t
      where . . .
     ) x
where x.cnt = (select count(*)
               from t
               where t.a_id = a.id and t.b_id in (2,3)
              );
```